# How to share session between two CodeIgniter applications in same domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, continuous-integration

**My Project Folder structure:**

```
=>TestProject (Main Folder)
     - applicationOne
     - applicationTwo
```

**How to use applicationOne session to applicationTwo directory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but you have to point session path to same directory in both sub applications in below code
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L377

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'path_of_session_directory'
```

and make sure your cookie domain is same in both application